# Convert a number to a letter postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

i have a function that convert a number to a letter.

i want to optimise this function. see query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2586d3e0b98df1c899defc7b4078e1ef

i want to have decimal part also.
now this function just return integer part.
example:

If i have 203.145, I want to get in letter 'Two hundred three point one hundred forty-five',

Now this function just return 'Two hundred three'

Query uses:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nombreenlettre1(
    nombre numeric)
    RETURNS text
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE STRICT PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
/* 
  Converti un nombre en lettre

  Exemple :  SELECT nombreenlettre(5423);
             cinq mille quatre cent vingt trois
 */
DECLARE
 unite text[]='{"un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six",
                "sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze",
                "treize","quatorze","quinze","seize"}';
 dizaine text[] ='{"vingt","trente","quarante","cinquante",
                   "soixante","","quatre-vingt"}';
 coefs text[] ='{"cent","mille","million","milliard"}';
 temps text;
 c int2;
 d int2;
 u int2;
 coef int2 = 0;
 i int2;
 neg boolean;
 resultat text = '';
 n bigint;
BEGIN
  n:=nombre;
  
  IF n=0 THEN
   return 'zéro';
  END IF;

  neg:=n<0;
  IF neg=true THEN
    n:=-n;
  END IF;

  LOOP
   u:=n%10;
   n:=n/10;
   d:=n%10;
   n:=n/10; 
   IF d in (1,7,9) THEN
     d:=d-1;
     u:=u+10;
   END IF;
   temps:='';
   IF d>1 THEN
    temps:=' '||dizaine[d-1];
    IF (d<8) and ((u=1) or (u=11)) THEN
     temps:=temps||' et';
    END IF;
   END IF;
   IF u>16 THEN
    temps:=temps||' '||unite[10];
    u:=u-10;
   END IF;
   IF u>0 THEN
    temps:=temps||' '||unite[u];
   END IF;
   IF (resultat='') and (d=8) and (u=0) THEN
    resultat:='s';
   END IF;
   resultat:=temps||resultat;
   c:=n%10;
   n:=n/10;
   IF c>0 then
    temps:='';
    IF c>1 THEN
     temps:=' '||unite[c]||temps;
    END IF;
    temps:=temps||' '||coefs[1];
    IF (resultat='') and (c>1) THEN
     resultat:='s';
    END IF;
    resultat:=temps||resultat;
   END IF;
   IF n>0 THEN
    coef:=coef+1;
    i:=n%1000;
    IF (i>1) and (coef>1) THEN
     resultat:='s'||resultat;
    END IF;
    IF i>0 THEN
     resultat:=' '||coefs[coef+1]||resultat;
    END IF;
    IF (i=1) and (coef=1) THEN
     n:=n-1;
    END IF;
   END IF;
   EXIT WHEN n=0;
  END LOOP;

  IF neg THEN
   resultat:='moins'||resultat;
  END IF;
  
  return resultat;
END;
$BODY$;
```

```sql
select nombreenlettre1(2053.234)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert in case you have floationg number in two parts , integer and floating and double call your function.
in fact the result you need for 2053.234 is

```
select concat(nombreenlettre1(2053), 'point', select nombreenlettre1(234))
```

you need just to wrap your function with a substr of your first float to get two degits.

Comment: how to do that please, can you do make this here : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3f503d68f546a2fbe26ee7cfabdc1bdc

Comment: i have a floating number in one part . like 203.05

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e7bc47d67496034a1389014128308843

Comment: sorry for the delay